# Print devise user session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, printing, devise

is there a way to print out the devise user session in rails? something like

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

in php?

thanks + regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

`<%= session.inspect %>`

in your Your view file